# Make my WCF service return json

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am trying to make my WCF service method to return JSON-object, but it doesn't work, when I open in a web browser it shows xml.

How can I make this method return JSON?

I have inserted [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)], but that didn't help

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]  
protected override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, SampleItem>> OnGetItems()  
{  
   // TODO: Change the sample implementation here  
   if (items.Count == 0)  
   {  
      items.Add("A", new SampleItem() { Value = "A" });  
      items.Add("B", new SampleItem() { Value = "B" });  
      items.Add("C", new SampleItem() { Value = "C" });  
   }  
   return this.items;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to host this with the `webHttpBinding` and the `WebServiceHostFactory` in your web.config and service's `*.svc` file.

You didn't show any web.config or other config - so I cannot really tell what you're doing. But the JSON response format in the `WebGet` attribute is only supported in the REST-style WCF services. The `WebGet` attribute is ignored for any of the SOAP-based bindings, e.g. `basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding`, `netTcpBinding` and so on.

For more information on REST-style WCF Services, check out the [WCF REST Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/WCF/REST) and read up on how to set up and use REST-style WCF services.

**Update:** in order for your *.svc file to properly work as a REST service that uses the `WebGet` attribute and returns JSON, you need to make sure to specify the correct service host factory:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="YourService"
               Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

By specifying the `WebServiceHostFactory`, you're telling the WCF runtime to use this service as a REST service, and then all the other pieces should automatically fall into place.

Comment: the example that you gave me is, .cs-file

Comment: what are the differences of .svc-file and .csfile, working as services

Answer (score 0):

Have you also set the WebHttpBehaviour ? Otherwise, WebGet does not work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412204.aspx)

And this attribute applies to Service operations, not simple methods. You do not show the rest of your services, but the examples I've seen using WebGet had this attribute in the interface (service contract).

Comment: Iam not using any indetface, iam using a -svc-file